# What is responsible for assigning and linking address for a variable?

Tags: c, memory

When we define a variable (lets talk about C coding in microcontroller), then it is stored in RAM and it has it own address. Then what is responsible for that action of assigning an address for that variable and link that address to a memory cell in ram? And about that address, it often looks like 0xXXXXXXXX, is that really an address of a memory cell in ram or just a virtual address?

If anyone has an answer for this, please explain to me. Thank you so much.

Comment: This depends on [storage and linkage specifiers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/storage_duration). It could be the compiler, it could be the linker.

Comment: It also depends on the platform your program is supposed to run on. For a microcontroller there are most likely no virtual adresses.

Comment: It's dependent on the compiler and architecture, and the address of the variable usually shouldn't concern you. It can be also stored in a register, or even be optimized away completely. The part about the "virtual address" is also unclear, if your architecture accesses external a certain RAM module at address `0x000C0000`, it's obviously not the exact "memory cell address" for that module, but the term virtual memory usually comes into play when you need to run multiple processes on an operating system, not with bare-bone uc programming.